# Count unique characters present in a group of columns

Tags: r, dplyr

I have the following dataset

```
dat <- data.frame(group = c(1,1,1,1,1), id = c(1,2,3,4,5),
              t1 = c('a','a','b','b','c'),p1 = c(0.98,1,0.5,0.9,1),
              t2 = c('b',NA,'a','c',NA),p2 = c(0.02,NA,0.25,0.10,NA),
              t3 = c(NA,NA,'c',NA,NA),p3 = c(NA,NA,0.25,NA,NA))
```

I am trying to count the number of unique characters present across multiple columns (t1,t2,t3) in a group encompassing multiple rows (variable = 'group'). Whether or not each character is counted depends on the associated p1,p2,p3 values being >= 0.05.

I have tried entering this code to count unique characters from all columns

```
b <- dat %>%
group_by(group) %>%
mutate(total = sum(n_distinct(t1[p1 >= 0.05], na.rm = TRUE),
                            n_distinct(t2[p2 >= 0.05], na.rm = TRUE),
                            n_distinct(t3[p3 >= 0.05], na.rm = TRUE)))
```

The results being that it counts the unique characters of t1, t2, and t3, and then sums that up resulting in the following dataset where 'total' is 6

```
dat <- data.frame(group = c(1,1,1,1,1), id = c(1,2,3,4,5),
              t1 = c('a','a','b','b','c'),p1 = c(0.98,1,0.5,0.9,1),
              t2 = c('b',NA,'a','c',NA),p2 = c(0.02,NA,0.25,0.10,NA),
              t3 = c(NA,NA,'c',NA,NA),p3 = c(NA,NA,0.25,NA,NA),
              total = c(6,6,6,6,6))
```

However, what I am looking to do is count the total number of unique characters across all of the columns. In other words, if 'a' was seen in column t1, then don't count 'a' in the other columns (t2,t3). The final product would look like the following dataset where 'total' is 3 (representing a,b, and c being the unique characters present)

```
dat <- data.frame(group = c(1,1,1,1,1), id = c(1,2,3,4,5),
              t1 = c('a','a','b','b','c'),p1 = c(0.98,1,0.5,0.9,1),
              t2 = c('b',NA,'a','c',NA),p2 = c(0.02,NA,0.25,0.10,NA),
              t3 = c(NA,NA,'c',NA,NA),p3 = c(NA,NA,0.25,NA,NA),
              total = c(3,3,3,3,3))
```

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `map2` to loop through the each of the corresponding 't' and 'p' columns, get the subset of columns in the `list`, `filter` the rows based on the values of 'p' column, `pull` the 't' column, get the number of distinct elements (`n_distinct`) and create a new column with `bind_cols`

```
library(tidyverse)
map2_int(paste0('t', 1:3), paste0('p', 1:3), ~ 
          dat %>%
             select(.x, .y)  %>% 
             filter_at(.y, all_vars(. >= 0.05)) %>%
             pull(.x) %>%
             n_distinct) %>% 
     bind_cols(dat, total = .)
```

and if it is 'unique' across the columns, then instead of getting the `n_distinct` per each column, `unlist` the `list` and then apply the `n_distinct`, then create the new column in 'dat' with `mutate`

```
map2(paste0('t', 1:3), paste0('p', 1:3), ~ 
          dat %>% 
            select(.x, .y)  %>%
            filter_at(.y, all_vars(. >= 0.05)) %>%
            pull(.x) ) %>% 
            unlist %>% 
            n_distinct %>% 
            mutate(dat, total = .)
#   group id t1   p1   t2   p2   t3   p3 total
#1     1  1  a 0.98    b 0.02 <NA>   NA     3
#2     1  2  a 1.00 <NA>   NA <NA>   NA     3
#3     1  3  b 0.50    a 0.25    c 0.25     3
#4     1  4  b 0.90    c 0.10 <NA>   NA     3
#5     1  5  c 1.00 <NA>   NA <NA>   NA     3
```

#### Update

If we do a `group_by` `n_distinct`, the above can be changed by `summarise`ing the `n_distinct` of 'total' after grouping by 'group'

```
map2_df(paste0('t', 1:3), paste0('p', 1:3), ~ 
      dat %>% 
         group_by(group) %>%
         select(.x, .y)  %>%
         filter_at(.y, all_vars(. >= 0.05))  %>% 
         select(-.y) %>% 
         rename_at(.x, ~ 'total')) %>% 
   summarise(total = n_distinct(total)) %>% 
   left_join(dat)
```

Answer (score 3):

First `lapply` though the `p` columns with the function `>= 0.05`, and then select rows where the result is true for all `p` columns with `Reduce('&'`. Once you have the rows, you can select the data for which you want to count uniques with `.SD[rows, paste0('t', 1:3)]`, and `unlist` it (coerce it to a single vector), which allows you to use `UniqueN` directly to count the uniques.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(dat)

dat[, total := {rows <- Reduce('&', lapply(.(p1, p2, p3), '>=', 0.05)) 
                uniqueN(unlist(.SD[rows, paste0('t', 1:3)]))}
    , by = group]



#    group id t1   p1   t2   p2   t3   p3 total
# 1:     1  1  a 0.98    b 0.02 <NA>   NA     3
# 2:     1  2  a 1.00 <NA>   NA <NA>   NA     3
# 3:     1  3  b 0.50    a 0.25    c 0.25     3
# 4:     1  4  b 0.90    c 0.10 <NA>   NA     3
# 5:     1  5  c 1.00 <NA>   NA <NA>   NA     3
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work for any number of groups and any number of column pairs.

```
dat %>%
  gather(key, value, -group, -id) %>%
  separate(key, c('key1', 'key2'), 1) %>%
  group_by(group, id, key2) %>%
  spread(key1, value) %>%
  filter(p >= 0.05) %>%
  pull(t) %>%
  n_distinct() %>% 
  mutate(dat, total = .)
```